# Are there any other sadhakas in India who lived without food?

Tags: history, yoga, food

In the scriptures of Sanathan Dharma, there are several mentions about rishis or yogis who live without food. Some may live on the water, some may live with either sun or air.

In the recent past, there are two such people: Giri Bala, and Prahlad Jani.

Detailed mention of the Giri Bala is found in [CHAPTER 46. THE WOMAN YOGI WHO NEVER EATS](https://zelalemkibret.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/the-autobiography-of-yogi.pdf#page=267) of the book **Autobiography of a Yogi** by *Paramhansa Yogananda*.

Prahlad Jani lived till *26 May 2020*. He lived for 90 years.

Although both of them eat food during their early childhood, they dropped eating food after spiritual experiences.

Are there any other people of this sort in India lived without food?

Comment: There is one who had cut his tongue and offered to mahadev after which he stopped taking food

Comment: @Youwillnotknowme Is it in scriptures or in History?

Comment: The man was alive 3-4 years ago don't know about present

Comment: Patanjali yoga Sutra do talk about kaya siddhi and kaya sampath in chap 2 and chap 3, but not sure of any explicit mention of a stage wherein a yogi rises above the need for food and water.Rev. st. Hanuman das baba ji vrindavan, could be one such great  living saint.

Comment: There could be in Himalayas definitely.

Comment: One who has tasted Amirta from sahsarara for him no need of food water sleep.